# Locating Inner Text with CSS or Xpath in Amazon

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am teaching myself automation with Selenium web driver, and thought a good way was to learn off an ecommerce site such as Amazon.  I am trying to locate inner text with CSS and used the following to verify logged in user name via page factory:

Locating Element with **CSS:**

```
@FindBy (how=How.CSS, using= "a:contains('Hello,Nichole')") WebElement
 loggedInUsernameText;
```

**Error Message:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: 
An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

Unfortunately this did not work for me, so I tried to use **XPath**:

```
@FindBy (how=How.XPATH, using= "//*[contains(text(),('Hello,Nichole')]") WebElement loggedInUsernameText;
```

**Error Message:**

```
    org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: 
    Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[contains(text(),('Hello,Nichole')] because of the following error:
    SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': 
The string '//*[contains(text(),('Hello,Nichole')]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

This didn't work for me either- can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is the locator for CSS and Xpath:

Hello, Nichole

CSS:

```
#nav-link-accountList > span.nav-line-1
```

XPath:

```
//*[@id="nav-link-accountList"]/span[1]
```

I am probably doing something really dumb! Let me know if I need to provide other information- oh to find it on the console it does specify to use $0- which I did use and it located it, so I am guessing I need to implement that somehow?

Comment: the element you are looking for is in an iFrame?

Comment: @YuZhang No, it is not in an iFrame-

Answer (score 4):

It's Pretty easy. Look at your XPath expression and the Syntax error:

You have added unwanted bracket `"()"` in your XPath.

Your **XPath** should be:

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Hello,Nichole')]
```

Using **Page-Factory**:

```
@FindBy (how=How.XPATH, using= "//*[contains(text(), 'Hello,Nichole')]")
 WebElement loggedInUsernameText;
```

Comment: It should definitely work, Let me know if you still have any problem with this.

Comment: @BharatMane-  thank you, yes I knew it was going to be something silly...thank you thank you

Comment: Could you please accept the answer,  if it works for you.

Comment: @BharatMane-  I just tried it and it didn't work...it is a cannot locate element error-

Comment: Could you please add your HTML code

Comment: <span class="nav-line-1">Hello, Nichole</span>

Comment: <a href="https://www.amazon.com/gp/css/homepage.html?ref=nav_youraccount_btn" class="nav-a nav-a-2 nav-truncate" data-nav-ref="nav_ya_signin" data-nav-role="signin" data-ux-jq-mouseenter="true" id="nav-link-accountList" tabindex="61">
  <span class="nav-line-1">Hello, Nichole</span>
  <span class="nav-line-2">Account &amp; Lists<span class="nav-icon nav-arrow" style="visibility: visible;"></span>
  </span>
  <span class="nav-line-3">Hi Nichole</span>
  <span class="nav-line-4">Account &amp; Lists</span>
</a>

Answer (score 0):

CSS for the element

```
#nav-link-accountList  span.nav-line-1
```

XPath for the element

```
//a[@id='nav-link-accountList']/div/span[@class='nav-line-1']
```

You can modify the @FindBy section for CSS

```
 @FindBy (how=How.CSS, using= "#nav-link-accountList  span.nav-line-1") 
 WebElement loggedInUsernameText;
```

Also you could shorten the element definition

```
@FindBy(css = "#nav-link-accountList  span.nav-line-1")
WebElement loggedInUsernameText;
```

[Mastering XPath](http://pragmatictestlabs.com/2020/01/28/mastering-xpath-for-selenium-test-automation-engineers/) and [Mastering CSS](http://pragmatictestlabs.com/2020/02/09/mastering-css-for-selenium-test-automation-2/) for Selenium test automation engineers could be useful.